# How to clean up a question which was completely changed after some answers were given?

Tags: discussion, support, questions

The top Google result (for me) for the search "two or more data types in declaration specifiers" is this question:

[Two or more data types in declaration specifiers error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098973/two-or-more-data-types-in-declaration-specifiers-error)

It has a perfectly valid answer, but at one point the question was a completely different one. I have seen plenty of meta questions on what to do if this is encountered before it gets any answers in its new form, but none on what to do if it has answers for both forms.

Is there anything which can be done now, or must we live with this forever?

Comment: It's a typo question, it got lots of upvotes because of the interesting behavior of the typo. The previous incarnation of the question was a basic debugging question. All in all, not much to see.

Comment: It looks to me like paxdiablo already fixed the problem back in 2010. What else would you want to do with it?

Comment: @CodyGray I feel that this was only partially fixed. The real fix would have been to roll it back immediately before it got other answers.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest cleaning up questions the same way this one was: rollback and comment.

If they insist on changing the question again, flag it and go on about your (potentially merry) way.

Comment: What if there is an answer for both versions?

Comment: @Teemu I think this is still the best answer, although rolling back to the original question might earn some downvotes for late answers. Putting a note in the comments would, in an ideal society, discourage that.